# pandas DataFrame columns named True and False work just fine

Tags: python, pandas

The sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2), columns=[True, False])
# All of the following works fine. Just like you would expect
# them to, if the columns had any other (string) name.
# (Because True == True, True == False and False == False are
# valid comparisons -- they have to be.)
df.loc[:, True]
df.loc[:, False]
df.loc[:, [col for col in df.columns if col]]
df.loc[:, :]

# However, the below line, only returns column `True`. But if
# the names were strings, it would return both columns.
df.loc[:, [True, False]]
```

What [witchcraft](http://www.mememaker.net/static/images/memes/2707704.jpg) makes this possible? I thought some check for keys will fail. But they didn't and I had to ask because they didn't.

So rephrasing my question: How does pandas (Python, for that matter) decide between Boolean and non-Boolean (for lack of better expression) indexing? How does it avoid confusion? And what prevents misbehavior? Had the first line (`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2), columns=[True, False])`) returned a single column (`True`) I would have been less surprised.

Comment: I dont understand your question - do you as why works list comprehension `print ([col for col in [True, False] if col == True])` ?

Comment: No no, I understand that I can check for `True == True` and `True == False` as valid tests. What I don't understand is how can a column be named `True` or `False` and not break anything. Even `df.loc[:, :]` works. So where does boolean indexing go?

Comment: Why did you think would fail, exactly? Indeed, try passing `columns=[0,1]` and it will also work just fine.

Comment: It also works nice with `print (df[True])`.

Comment: Hmm, boolean columns names are more rare, but it works nice, becasue loc selects by labels.

Comment: See the edit people! I tried to explain why my head just exploded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no witchcraft. As far as I know, columns can be labeled by any hashable type. Given that booleans are instances of ints, is it really any more strange than:

```
In [7]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2), columns=[0, 1])

In [8]: df1
Out[8]: 
          0         1
0  0.706135  0.307180
1  0.713418  0.006204
2  0.308810  0.688868
3  0.582871  0.738771
4  0.418600  0.948231
```

However, since `.loc` lets you select by label, there is one way where boolean labels will be ambiguous. Consider what I can do with my `int` labelled columns:

```
In [10]: df1.loc[:, [1, 0]]
Out[10]: 
          1         0
0  0.307180  0.706135
1  0.006204  0.713418
2  0.688868  0.308810
3  0.738771  0.582871
4  0.948231  0.418600
```

However, if I try to do the same thing with the boolean labelled columns:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
      True      False
0  0.487752  0.545283
1  0.921928  0.715808
2  0.618667  0.946385
3  0.975142  0.078050
4  0.994348  0.468887

In [12]: df.loc[:, [False, True]]
Out[12]: 
      False
0  0.545283
1  0.715808
2  0.946385
3  0.078050
4  0.468887
```

Whoops! now it is reverting to boolean indexing behavior. Still, you can always use `.iloc`:

```
In [13]: df.iloc[:, [1, 0]]
Out[13]: 
      False     True 
0  0.545283  0.487752
1  0.715808  0.921928
2  0.946385  0.618667
3  0.078050  0.975142
4  0.468887  0.994348
```

### Edit to address OP edit

Notice, however, that `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2), columns=[True, False])` is works fine because it isn't an indexing or selection operation, it is creating a DataFrame. Finally, notice that:

```
In [17]: df.loc[:, [False]]
Out[17]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Also uses boolean indexing on the columns, as expected. So, it reverts to boolean indexing as far as I can tell.

## Edit by asker

Do also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38930045/3765319) to the question to get the other part of the story.

Comment: Great answer. But where does the switch between label based and Bool based indexing happen? I know `.iloc` will work just fine, because it uses indexes, and indexes don't care what they point to.

Comment: Hmmm, and what about `print (df.loc[:, [False]])` and `print (df[[False]])` ?

Comment: @jezrael the former is giving me boolean indexing behavior (returning an empty DataFrame) and the latter is giving me an error since boolean slicing using DataFrame.getitem (i.e. df[boolean_vec]) selects *rows*

Comment: @jezrael hmmm I don't think it's a bug. Try `df[[True,False,True,False,True]]`, which selects rows as expected. Now try `df[[True,False,True,False,True,False]]` and I get another `ValueError`

Comment: Ya, nice boolean indexing also, yes, you are right.

Comment: So probably it takes whatever you pass to the `.loc` and checks it's type before deciding what to use, Boolean or label based indexing. But that does not explain how `.loc[:, False]` just returns the `False` column... Any idea?

Comment: @Kartik Because it is a single label, so it can't be a boolean selection. It assumes it's a label. Try `df1.loc[:False]` (using the DataFrame with `columns=[1,0]` and you'll get a `KeyError`

Answer (score 1):

There is no witchcraft!

The cool thing about `loc` is that you can pass boolean masks along side label indexing.  The developers decided that if `loc` sees an array like structure of boolean values... then its going to be a mask.

```
df[False]

0    0.385615
1    0.212807
2    0.312314
3    0.826243
4    0.431003
dtype: float64
```

---

```
df.loc[:, False]

0    0.385615
1    0.212807
2    0.312314
3    0.826243
4    0.431003
dtype: float64
```

---

```
# Looks like a mask
df.loc[:, [False]]

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here's an idea.  Don't play with bizarre edge cases and expect everything to be perfect.  Just use normal column labels.  I also wouldn't try to fly a helicopter in a vacuum and ask why it didn't fly.

Comment: I was expecting it to not work at all. I was expecting pandas would slap me with a `ValueError` or a `TypeError` for passing Boolean column names. Borrowing from your example -- but using a twin prop instead of a helicopter -- I was expecting to crash hard the moment vacuum was turned on. But it seemed as if I was flying with one engine. That's what surprised me. And I was just fooling around because I was bored. Nothing important. Nice answer.